# Build nested dictionary in shell script

Tags: python, shell, dictionary

My aim is to create a dictionary structure as mentioned below in shell script and pass that as an argument to a python script. I can build that dictionary in python script itself by passing all variable value from shell. Actually that will be too much of arguments for my python script.

```
{ 
   "a": "Hello",
   "b": { 
      "c": { 
         "key": "value1"
      }, 
      "d": { 
         "key2": "value2"
      }
   }
}
```

Where `a, b, c, d, key2, key2` are string values stored in different variables.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: for Python it will be only string which you will have to parse (or probably use `json` to convert to Python data) - you can put all data in one line as one string/argument. `python main.py '{"a":"Hello","b":{"c":{"key":"value1"},"d":{"key2":"value2"}}}'`

Comment: Perhaps put the data from the shell script into a temporary file, and pass the file name of that file to your Python script? That way you won't have to deal with any restriction on the size of the command (or, as a bonus, its formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a json file with your dictionary and pass to python script with argparse

For example:

```
import os
import argparse
import json


def execute(json_file):
    if os.path.isfile(json_file):
        with open(json_file) as json_data:
            data = json.load(json_data)
            # here you can process your dictionary data
            print data


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This script will take json file as argument")
parser.add_argument('json')
arg = parser.parse_args()
json_file = arg.json
execute(json_file)
```

open command shell and enter:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe argDict.py C:\temp.json
```